# Logic error in loop

Tags: c, file, loops, logic

Trying to add values to my struct Player but my output for them after operation is junk:

Output looks like:

```
    Name: Warner
    runs: 0
    not out: 0
    how out: |||||||| (symbols)
```

Player is a struct:

```
Player {

int not_out, innings, runs;

char pname[MAX_NAME];

char how_out[5];

}
```

Here's my code:

```
void scan_stats (Team_t player[]) {

int i, status, runs, turns;
char out;
char string[MAX_PLYR];


FILE *inp;

inp = fopen("teamstats.txt", "r");

do 
{

    fscanf(inp, "%s" "%d" "%*c" "%c", &string, &runs, &out);

    printf("%s    %d     %c\n", string, runs, out); /*They scan perfectly*/

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_PLYR; i++) {

        player[i].innings = 0;

        player[i].runs = 0; 

        player[i].not_out = 0;

        turns = -1;

        if (status = (strcmp(player[i].pname, string)) == 0) {

            player[i].innings = player[i].innings + 1;

            player[i].runs = player[i].runs + runs;

            turns = turns + 1;

            if (out == 'n') {

                player[i].not_out = player[i].not_out + 1;

            }

            else {

                player[i].how_out[turns] = out;

            }
        }
    }
} while (!feof(inp));    /*Printing the values of player at the end of this loop 
                               produces garbage/ incorrectness*/
fclose(inp);
}
```

Comment: What does the code that prints it look like?  Is the problem the "how out" output or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You never place a closing `'\0'` in player[i].how_out - you just place `char`s in it. Then, you try to print it as a string. At this point, `printf` just prints whatever if finds until it gets to a random NULL, and that's the garbage you get.

To fix this, make sure player[i].how_out has a '\0' (or `NULL`) after the last char - and make sure the buffer is large enough for that extra NULL.